# ASP.NET Core 2.1 to 3.1 upgrade perfomance problem

Tags: asp.net, .net

I needed to update a version on a large and old project. I did that, resolved all conflicts, and the project is now running on version 3.1. But I have a problem with page loading speed. On version 2.1, pages load at about the following speed:
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci5wE.png)
On version 3.1 with this:
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQlke.png)
[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIPvO.png)
This VivResult takes approximately 2 seconds on any of the pages.
I didn't find any information about this anywhere. Is this correct behavior or am I doing something wrong? Why is this happening? Is it possible to avoid this? Thanks.

Updated:
I can see the same problem and the same about 2 seconds request in default empty project without any sql queries.
[image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vu3y.png)

Comment: You should be migrating to .NET 6 not .NET Core 3.1. 3.1 reaches End Of Life this year. The current Long Term Support version is 6.0 which will be supported until 2024

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I understand it, and I planned to do it after upgrade to 3.1. Am I wrong?

Comment: As for the question itself we can't guess what the code does. .NET Core 3.1 *improved* performance significantly. Without your code we have to guess. My guess is that the old code depended on EF Core 2 quirks. EF Core 2 couldn't translate all LINQ queries and often resorted to client-side evaluation or executing multiple queries to get the same data. EF Core 3 fixed this and generates a single query with JOINs by default. If the query is too complex or the tables lack indexes, that query could be slower.

Comment: In EF 5 and later you can use [split queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries)

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos . Then, why is empty default templated project, version 6.0 showing the same result? There is no database. I`m just trying to understand. Added screenshot to the question.

Comment: The default template doesn't use Miniprofiler. Post the code you actually used. Is this the first call? Do you encounter such delays on every call? Are you running this under a debugger or not? You're asking people to guess

Comment: I just created a new web app with `dotnet new webapp`. First load 500ms. Subsequent refreshes take 40ms. Similar results with `dotnet new mvc`

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos . I tested it on another pc, and it`s working fast and good. By the way, my pc has 32gb RAM and intel core i5.  And in task manager it`s not overloaded, only 5-10% of presure. Anyway, thank you. Maybe, problem with my IIS.

Comment: Running a web app from the command line doesn't use IIS. You'd have to use an IDE to start under IIS, or deploy the app then access it. At that point you'd pay for the warmup but that only happens once. And 5% is StackOverflow's normal load. This is too much for an idle web app. Whatever the problem is, it's not IIS itself. In fact, IIS is the fast option because the site is always up. If your IDE uses IIS *Express*, then yes, there's a delay because IIS Express needs to start again every time you start your web app from your IDE.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos . Yes, I using  IIS Express with Visual Studio. Interesting thing that another pc using the same setup)